# Azure Data Factory remove csv extension name during copy activity to SQL DB

Tags: csv, expression, azure-data-factory, trim

This is the following use case:

I have different csv files from my data lake and want to copy this to my Azure SQL DB. a typical file name of the csv looks like this :  Sale-Internet-Header.csv.

In the Sink property of Azure SQL DB i used the expression in the sink dataset  **@replace(item().name, '-','_')**.
After execute the copy pipeline the sql table has the following name: dbo.sales_internet_header.csv

I would like to change my expression in the sink dataset to remove the ".csv" so that the SQL table name going to look like : dbo.sales_internet_header

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` and add dynamic content
`@replace(variables('cc'),'.csv', '')` remove the ".csv".

Give this dynamic content in the SQL dataset table name or inside ForEach as above. Here is the sample demonstration that  where I have used set variable to replace the `.csv`.

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunatly using your expression @replace(variables('cc'),'.csv', '')   it returns only the following sql table name : dbo.Sale-Internet-Header. i was expecting to have this result : dbo.Sale_Internet_Header.